# Flutter integration test Binding Error - overrode FlutterError.onError

Tags: integration-testing, flutter-integration-test

I tried to create a test for my flutter app with integration_test. There is some error when i tried to run the test. Here's the error on the terminal:

> 'package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart': Failed assertion: line 810 pos 14: '_pendingExceptionDetails != null': A test overrode FlutterError.onError but either fail
> ed to return it to its original state, or had unexpected additional errors that it could not handle. Typically, this is caused by using expect() before restoring Flut
> terError.onError.

Here's my code :

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('Test_Login_Using_Robo', (tester) async {
    app.main();
    await tester.pump();
    await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    final phoneNumberLoginTextField = find.byKey(const Key('phoneNumberTextField'));
    await tester.tap(phoneNumberLoginTextField);
    expect(phoneNumberLoginTextField, findsOneWidget);
    await tester.enterText(phoneNumberLoginTextField, '82220099611');

    await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key('loginButton')));

    ///Wait user for loggin in
    await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 5));

    ///We Expect to see the otp Screen
    expect(find.byType(OTPControllerScreen), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Which part is resulting this error ? how to fix this ? thanks before

Comment: Related error and possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67293968/how-to-restore-fluttererror-onerror